# Why doesn't Python mocker resolve to a immutable value?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

How do you make Python's `unittest.mock.patch` return an object that lets you assign a callable return value?

For example, I have a custom class in `myclass.py` defined as:

```
class MyClass:

    @property
    def someprop(self):
        return 'you should never see this in a test'
```

I want to test a function that acts on data retrieved from `someprop`. In my real application, `someprop` actually calls some complicated external database that's not accessible in a unittest, and isn't really necessary for the purposes of the unittest, so I decide to mock a return value using the `patch` and the `faker` package.

So my unittest looks like:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock
from faker import Faker
from myclass import MyClass

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.mock.patch('myclass.MyClass.someprop')
    def test_mock_error(self, mock_myclass_someprop):
    
        class RandomText:
            @property
            def text(self):
                factory = Faker()
                return factory.text()
    
        # Make calls to someprop return random text.
        mock_myclass_someprop.return_value = RandomText.text
        
        a = MyClass()
        actual_text = a.someprop
        print('actual text:', actual_text)
        self.assertTrue('MagicMock' not in str(actual_text)) # this fails

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Every time the test runs, the patch causes it to access the `text` property on my `RandomText` instance instead of `someprop`, which should return a unique string. However, this fails because the mock is actually returning a value like `<MagicMock name='someprop' id='140126618001360'>`.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

I've tried refactoring how I set and call `return_value`, but no matter what I do, it returns a `MagicMock` instance instead of a real return value retrieved from my patched callable.